# What can be put inside a Synchronized Block?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I know that a block of code or instance can be put into a synchronized block. So consider this short example:

```
public class SynchronizedObject {   
    public static void main(String args){
        System.out.println(" 1 " );

        synchronized(args){     
            //do stuff  
        }
```

In this case, the args is an instance am I correct? And this instance is also an object? Under no circumstances can you put variables or local variables into a sync block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is unclear. You seem to mix block and statements:

- the synchronized block, in your example, is whatever is inside the curly braces, so the `//do stuff` part.
- `args`, in your example, is the lock used by the `synchronized` statement.

You would probably benefit from reading a [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html).

> What can be put inside a Sychronized Block?

Anything you want as long as it is valid java statements.

> the args is an instance am I correct?

args is a reference to an instance of `String` (although you probably meant `String[]`).

> this instance is also an object?

Well, yes, an instance of a class IS an object.

> Under no circumstances can you put variables or local variables into a sync block?

Inside the block, you can do what you want as explained above. The argument to the `synchronized` keyword (the lock) needs to be a reference to a non null instance of an Object. That could be a local variable if you want (although that will most likely not achieve your goal).

Answer (score 2):

In this case `args` is a local variable - and its an instance of the `String` class.  And `String` is indeed an `Object` as all classes in Java are derived from `Object`

There is no restriction on putting local variables in a sync block - theres not much to gain by doing it, but there are no restrictions on it either.

You dont gain anything useful by synchronizing on a local variable though.